# Add own columns in a binded DataGridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that gets a datasource assigned.
I would like to create my own columns if it's (for example) DateTime.
I found an example of how you can create a DateTimePicker ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28VS.80%29.aspx)) (and hopefully also a NumericUpDown) to add to the datagrid, but I don't know how i can define this column  to my datagrid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the last method in your example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

This is where the columns are added to the `DataGridView`. You can use the same way to add any column object **derived from** `DataGridViewColumn` to your grid.

**[Edit]**

Before binding, set the [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28VS.80%29.aspx) property to `false` and add your custom columns.

You will also have to set the [`DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname%28VS.80%29.aspx) property for each column, to define which property will be bound to which column:

```
CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Date"; // if your class has a "Date" property
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: But as I see it, here you define your own columns. If you bind them, te columns are autogenerated, how do I interecept that and add this type of code?

Comment: The columns don't have to be autogenerated, you can just set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false...